# Express an expression in terms of other expressions in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

Is there any way to express an expression in terms of other expressions in MATLAB?

For example, the following expressions have been written as sum (X + Y) and product (XY)

```
1/X + 1/Y = (X + Y)/XY

1/X^2 + 1/Y^2 + 2/(XY) = (X + Y)^2/(XY)

2*X/Y + 2*Y/X = 2*((X + Y)^2 - 2*X*Y)/(XY)
```

I know about the [rewrite()](https://in.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/rewrite.html) function but I couldn't find how it can be used to do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different functions you can try to change the format of your symbolic expression:

- [`collect`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/collect.html): collects coefficients (can specify an expression to collect powers of):

  ```
  >> collect(1/X + 1/Y)

  ans =

  (X + Y)/(Y*X)
  ```
- [`simplify`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html): perform algebraic simplification:

  ```
  >> simplify(1/X^2 + 1/Y^2 + 2/(X*Y))

  ans =

  (X + Y)^2/(X^2*Y^2)
  ```
- [`numden`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/numden.html): convert to a rational form, with a numerator and denominator:

  ```
  >> [n, d] = numden(2*X/Y + 2*Y/X)

  n =

  2*X^2 + 2*Y^2

  d =

  X*Y

  >> n/d

  ans =

  (2*X^2 + 2*Y^2)/(X*Y)
  ```

Comment: Thanks @gnovice. :) Is there a way to convert X^2 + Y^2 to (X + Y)^2 - 2*X*Y in MATLAB? I only want the final answers in the form (X + Y) or XY.